# printf not printing correctly

Tags: c, file-io

I have code that prompts the user for a filename, then displays the contents of the file on the console.  However, the printf() statement I use won't print out until the very end, so the user doesn't know to input a filename.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
printf("%s", "What file would you like to open?\t");
char filename[100];
scanf("%[^\n]", filename);
printf("You chose:\t%s\n", filename);
return 0;
}
```

The program currently scans the console, then prints out both printf() statements.  The scanf() statement works correctly, just not at the right time.  Any idea what my problem is?

EDIT: the program works correctly when run from the command line, but the problem persists  in Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `fflush(stdout);` after the first printf, I think the issue is with `printf` not flushing it's buffer.

EDIT: It seems that it's a [known bug in Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=173732), the workaround would be to set the buffer size to zero (check the comments for the code).

Comment: is the stdout related? I thought scanf use stdin?

Comment: I added that line to the program and it's still not working in Eclipse.

Comment: @nh0815 then, can you try adding `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, 0, _IONBF);` before your printf and seeing if that works?